# Variable being passed as a property not rendering in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties, components

New to react and I'm assuming this will be an easy question for someone but I can't find a specific question that answers this issue. I did a react tutorial and afterwards I decided to test myself by adding a few more functional buttons to the webpage. First, the webpage looks like this : 
[image]

What I want to do is display the total count of all of the counters (the array can vary in size etc) next to the total count. Currently I am doing that like this: 
First, my navbar component :

```
const NavBar = ({ totalCounters }, { totalCount }) => {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
      <a className="navbar-brand" href="www.thisisirellevant.com">
        Navbar{" "}
        <span className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">
          # of Nonzero Counters: {totalCounters}
        </span>
        <span className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary m-2">
          Total Count: {totalCount}
        </span>
      </a>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

And now how I am rendering this in the parent:

```
const sum = this.sumValues();
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavBar
          totalCounters={this.state.counters.filter((c) => c.value > 0).length} //this is a little different becuase we made it a functional component (it only raises events)
          totalCount={sum}
        />
```

(Not showing the entire fragment, the fragment does close eventually)
And finally the sum function I created in the App class:

```
sumValues() {
    var sum = 0;
    var counter;
    for (counter in this.state.counters) {
      sum += counter["value"];
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

Could anyone tell me why the Total Count is not being displayed? I feel like I am passing everything around correctly and returning an integer from the sum function, but as you can see from the image above nothing is ever rendered in its place. Any tips would be appreciated, sorry for such a novice question. Thanks all!

Comment: `({ totalCounters }, { totalCount })` should be `({ totalCounters, totalCount })` props is just one single object

Comment: Thank you. When I do that, the span renders as NaN. Any idea why this is?

Comment: `NaN` stands for "not a number", it usually happens when you add a number to `undefined`, which means counter.value is `undefined`, which is because you are using `for... in` which iterates through the keys, not the values, so you are are basically accessing the property `value` of an array index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from obvious `({ totalCounters }, { totalCount })` mistake in `NavBar` component I would suggest using `for of` loop when computing sum.

**Example**

```js
const { Component, useState, useEffect } = React;

const NavBar = ({ totalCounters, totalCount, isComputing }) => {
  return <div>
    <div>Counters: {totalCounters}</div>
    {isComputing ? <div>Computing count...</div> : <div>Count: {totalCount}</div>}
  </div>
}
 
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.sumValues = this.sumValues.bind(this);
    
    this.state = {
      count: -1,
      isComputing: true,
      counters: Array(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)).fill(0).map((pr, index) => ({value: index}))
    }
    this.mounted = false;
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.mounted = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      
      const count = this.sumValues();
      const isComputing = false;
      if(this.mounted) {
        this.setState(state => ({...state, count, isComputing}))
      }
    }, 300);
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
  }
  
  sumValues() {
    let sum = 0;
    const { counters } = this.state;
    
    for (let { value } of counters) {
      sum += value;
    }
    return sum;
  }

  render() {
    const { counters, count, isComputing } = this.state;
  
    return <div>
       <NavBar
            totalCounters={counters.filter((c) => c.value > 0).length}
            totalCount={count}
            isComputing={isComputing}
          />
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Ideally you would add another state `count` which can store your calculation.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much. So if I only change the props issue, the value would then render as NaN. When I calculate sum using your method, I get the desired result. Could you tell me why that is by chance? Just trying to understand whats going on so I don't repeat mistakes. Thank you. Also, can a component have multiple states? I didn't think this was possible.

Comment: [for in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) gets you keys of object or indexes in case of array. You'd have to call somewhere `array[index]` or `obj[key]` when you use it. What I meant by *another state* is just another property in `this.state` object. Updated answer